# Fuzzy or sharp RDD?

Tags: causality, fuzzy, regression-discontinuity

I am looking at the causal effect of a Danish retirement reform, where individuals born after 1954 have an increased normal retirement age. Therefore, the cutoff of the treatment is clear. However, depending on when you were born after 01.01.1954, the normal retirement age differs. Specifically, for every six months the retirement age increases by another six months. Therefore, the treatment is not the same for everyone who is treated. Hence, I thought a fuzzy RDD might be more fitting than a sharp RDD. However, the 'fuzzy' variable of what normal retirement age you face does not indicate any probability of treatment. Rather it just indicates to what level you are affected by the policy change.

My question is therefore whether a fuzzy RDD is fitting for this, or if not, there might be something better fitting for estimation of the effect than the sharp RDD.